# How to adjust the unbalanced margins of a pdf file in adobe acrobat pro

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I've a pdf file, whose margins are not, deservedly, set. As the image does show, left margin is something considerable, in comparison with the right one, which is trivial: [Typical pdf page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bq4W.png).

[image]

I am eager to *decrease the left margin and increase the right margin to acquire a centered block of text in every page of the booklet.* The current tool is adobe acrobat pro.

**Is there any idea to handle the issue?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just set the margins by means of `LaTeX` and acquired what I wanted by choosing right values for **offset**:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper, total={297mm, 210mm}}
\setboolean{@twoside}{false}

\begin{document}
     \includepdf[pages=-, offset=-10 -10]{fff.pdf}
\end{document}
```